# By which library etc. can i parse these type of data? in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, text-parsing

I'm sorry if it's a very easy question.
But how/by which library etc. can i parse a data like below in C++ ?

```
 (car
 (position
  (x 2500)
  (y 3000)
  (z 1200)
 )
 (appearance
  (color blue)
  (type sport)
 )
)
```

Comment: Use C++ to write a Lisp interpreter.  Then simply run that data through the interpreter.

Comment: Lisp interpreter in 90 lines of C++ : http://howtowriteaprogram.blogspot.com/2010/11/lisp-interpreter-in-90-lines-of-c.html

Answer (score 4):

sounds like a good candidate for [boost spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/).

Comment: boost.spirit is definitely awesome for these types of parsing problems. But it is not exactly suited for beginners (have you ever heard of someone not knowing how to parse simple text, and at the same time be comfortable with template meta-programming?). I would just suggest a simple home-brewed parser to the OP, just using good-ol' std::stringstream.

Comment: @Mikael, definitely not for the faint hearted, I agree. But I think one of the neat things with spirit is that you don't have to be a meta programming guru to get it up and running. At the same time, you can handroll your own using strings and streams, but I'd hazard that if the formatting changed slightly from the above, you'll be doing a lot more work to get it fixed again. The OP was asking for a library, and this makes sense, if you're prepared to spend a little time to understand the docs.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like [LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29). Assuming it's a homework question, writing a simple recursive descent parser for LISP is quite trivial, so I'd write my own parser if I were you.

Answer (score -2):

Don't think I've ever seen a format like that!  I'd be tempted to roll my own parser.

Or, write a code generator to convert it to XML.  Then there are plenty of libraries.

But there might be an easier answer out there.

Comment: Convert it to XML? But to do that, he'd need to parse it... :)

Comment: @Mac: And then do what with it?  The OP doesn't say, but presumably he wants to do something useful with them.  There are lots of existing facilities to do pretty much whatever you want with XML.  It's a variation of "write your own parser" but why the dislike for my answer while others are getting voted up?  I don't understand.

Comment: I've igored the fact that you're suggesting the OP roll their own parser despite the fact they are looking for a library, since the other questions did the same. However, while I appreciate that XML is **useful**, the OP hasn't mentioned any need to get XML output, and so rolling a parser as well as an XML output layer is (probably) redundant - all they really need is the parser. It's like me asking you if you can suggest a good builder to build me a beach house, and you saying "I'd recommend building your house yourself, and adding a pool". I want a builder, and don't need the pool...

Comment: This is hardly the complexity of building a beach house.  Maybe a tire swing.  But I guess the XML part could be akin to providing an easy chair on top of the board: http://www.bowdoin.edu/~disrael/what-the-customer-really-needed/

Comment: A much better analogy! And thanks for the link to the picture - that brings back memories...